# how to get query string params from api in react Native

Tags: react-native

https://obikes.page.link/d6o5/?ref=10959bc
I am using axios this is my invite link in my app i want to get data after query string i need ref code ref=10959bc ,how can i get this query data 10959bc in react native
i am unable to find any solution

```
React.useEffect(async () => {
    const getValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    
    await getReferal().then(response => {
      console.log(response.data.refferalUrl); //https://obikes.page.link/d6o5/?ref=10959bc
      //  refer code 
  
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear, you want to get the query paramters of the response?

Answer (score 1):

A pure JS approach:

```
React.useEffect(async () => {
    const getValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    
    await getReferal().then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.refferalUrl);
        // refer code:
        const url = response.data.refferalUrl
        let regex = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g, params = {}, match;
        while ((match = regex.exec(url))) {
            params[match[1]] = match[2];
        }
        console.log(params) // => {ref: "10959bc"}  
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the qs npm package to get the query string params from a string.

https://github.com/ljharb/qs